# MySQL keeps closing connections

Tags: mysql

After every 8 hours of an idle_connection MySQL keeps closing the connection. I want to make it so MySQL will never close an idle_connection how would I do this?

Comment: Your server would eventually run out of ports and it would crash. WHY would you want to do this?

Comment: @JoePhillips After 8 hours it just keeps closing an inactive connection causing my program to crash

Comment: Why is your program unable to detect this and reconnect?

Comment: @S.Z5938 Your program can't automatically reconnect? This is a commonly found setting. What language are you writing the code in?

Comment: Add a timer to your program (if it's possible with a language that you are using) and send every N minutes a query `SELECT 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must access the `my.cnf` file. It should be in your `etc` directory.

Find where it says

`wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800`

This says that MySQL will timeout after 28800 seconds (8 hours). Change it to whatever you want.

However, like is said in the comments, you probably should not do this.....

Comment: This does not adequately explain how to set it to INFINITE time

Comment: Set it to 1,000,000,000. That should last you about 30 years. By which time the server will have either broken, become obsolete, or HOPEFULLY someone would have used it!